# COM: can I see if there is an out-of-process reference to one of my COM objects? Can I release it?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl, cross-process

I have an application that makes a COM object accessible to external clients (by registering it in the ROT).

The object is implemented in C++ using ATL.

Question 1: Is it possible to determine whether one of the references held to my object originates from an out-of-process client?

Motivation: I need to release some related objects (that block some operations) when external references are removed, even when the external reference dies unexpectedly. I also want to avoid requiring the caller to "say goodbye".

I am using the same interface internally, so I can't work with a separate reference count for the interface. The exposed interface is `IDispatch`-based, so no custom marshaling takes place.

Question 2: Is it possible to tell out-of-process references to an object (and/or all objects) that the object is no longer "alive"? Forcing any call on the out-of-process interface to return, e.g. `RPC_E_DISCONNECTED` (in the same way as after terminating the server process, the client receives an `RPC_E_SERVER_DIED` for every call).

Motivation: the shutdown process of the server may be initiated by the user, and may take a while. In that time, all calls from external clients block; it would be prudent to inform them earlier that the call does not succeed.

Comment: i think that you need implement [`IExternalConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-iexternalconnection) interface on your object

Comment: and [`CoDisconnectObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-codisconnectobject) for 2

Comment: @RbMm: thanks, works as expected. if you want to post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

External references can be monitored by implementing [IExternalConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-iexternalconnection), you get called when an external connection is added or removed.

[CoDisconnectObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-codisconnectobject) allows you to tell an external connection to "go away" (though it seems like the external caller may not be notified immediately, the messgae loop may need to be active).